# Download data using big query

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a very big table(around 10 Billion rows) and have access to big query. I tried `Select * from table`. It returns all values and I want to download this data to my local machine. I don't have any access to buckets. I tried using GUI, there is a limit of 16000 rows only. I tried running a query `bq extract table` but it needs `URI` of the bucket.

Can someone point me to right direction to download this data.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to export data from BigQuery is to export it as files to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) within a `bq extract table` job.

An `URI` of the bucket means you need to create a bucket in GCS, so it can host the output files - that you can download later.

It should be all explained on: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

Comment: I have seen this answer earlier in stack overflow. In my question I mentioned that I dont have access to bucket in GCS. I'm looking for other ways to get the data.

Comment: Why don't you have access to GCS?

Comment: It's not my personal one and I got only viewer access. I want to download this table without asking for access. If there is no other solution then I would ask for bucket access.

Comment: Ok. You can export a table to any GCS bucket. If you can query BigQuery, you already have a GCP account - and you can use that GCP account to create your own personal buckets, unrelated to the project that hosts the data in BigQuery. You don't need to "ask for bucket access" for this.